# The method multiply(long) from the type BigInteger is not visible

Tags: java, error-handling, visibility, biginteger

I'm trying to run this code:

```
private static String reverseNumbers(BigInteger binaryBig){
    BigInteger big = new BigInteger("0");
    big.multiply(2);
}
```

But I get the error message: "The method multiply(long) from the type BigInteger is not visible". 
Why do I get this error and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Did you look up the Javadoc for `BigInteger` to see what type of parameter the `multiply` method has?

Comment: I guess I didn't look carefully enough, I was fooled by the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a package-private `multiply(long)` method in the `BigInteger` class, and you are attempting to call it from outside the package, so you get the error that the method isn't visible.  It looks from the source code that this method shows up starting in Java 6.

There is a `public` overload, [`multiply(BigInteger)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#multiply-java.math.BigInteger-).  Use it instead.  (Also you'll want to assign the result back to another variable.)

```
big = big.multiply(new BigInteger("2"));
```

Comment: @Calsal I would also add that it is slightly better to write `BigInteger.ZERO` and `BigInteger.valueOf(2)` rather than `new BigInteger("0")` and `new BigInteger("2")`. `BigInteger` values between `-16` and `16` are cached.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I will use those instead!

Comment: Do you by chance know why this overload is not public? To me it looks like adding int/long overloads to BigInteger operations would help with both convenience and possibly performance.